# How do I IPXE boot and gain or mount access to my IPXE Boot Server so I can run a program that uses database?

Tags: boot, networking, mount, filesystem

My problem is: How do I IPXE boot and gain or mount access to my IPXE Boot Server so I can run a program that uses database?

I need to PXE or IPXE and then run the program, but I need data after the program runs. I can boot from network and have the program run, but it does not have access to the file system. I can save data as text files, or maybe pdf to a usb flash drive, but I want to use a database and save the files on the IPXE Boot Server.

I have not figured out how to get from bootable Read-Only Media to mounting the file system of my server to gain access to it.

Currently, this is as far as I have gotten and learned: I can PXE boot. I can IPXE boot. I figured (out from much reading) how to IPXE boot with: vmlinux and initrd with imgargs ( though no Linux Guru, more dangerous than anything.:( )

But with all the "boot to Linux" methods, I am not sure which method is best? I think One with a small size and foot print, also it just needs be small and work well enough to get file system mounted properly.

I'm just learning about Linux and using it more so I apologize if it appears I should know this. ( Looking dumb).

Comment: I suggest you read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as I see nothing on-topic in your question for this site. This is a Ubuntu specific Q&A site, with Linux supported on SE *Unix & Linux*, and the kernel Linux (*used by Ubuntu yes, but also used on Android phones & more*) isn't on-topic here unless the question is specific to an on-topic OS/product/release & topic.

Comment: My main server I am using is Ubuntu. The Ubuntu installation, DHCP Server, FTP, TFTP, NFS, DNS, etc.. is all Ubuntu COMPLETELY RELATED to Ask Ubuntu site. All commands and packages like using IPXE and mounting a filesystem via IPXE or NFS is related to the packages, and Total Solution I want to accomplish. The packages and technologies are related and tied together with the main focus being the Unbuntu being used as the server. As an example, if I ask a question about binwalk, though not Ubuntu if using on Ubuntu and trying to get it to work properly, then it is a legit question.

Comment: @guiverc I am brand new so please don't skewer me. I'll look at the guidelines. Thank you for your assistance.